# How can I prove $\lim_{x\to \infty } \left(x(x+1) \log \left(\frac{x+1}{x} \right)-x\right)=\frac12$ for high school level?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have tried to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \left(x(x+1) \log \left(\dfrac{x+1}{x} \right)-x\right)=\frac12$$

using $\lim_ {x\to \infty }\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=e$, and using the variable change $z=\dfrac{1}{x}$ to get some known and standrad limit related to $\log$ natural logarithm properties function but I didn't succeed? Then any way and it's good if there is a suitable way for high school level.

Comment: $$\log (\frac{x+1}{x} )=\log (1+\frac{1}{x} )= \frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{2x^2} +\frac{1}{3x^3} - \ldots$$ when $x>1$

Comment: Thanks , but is there anyway available for high school student

Comment: But if you are not allowed to use Taylor series (an unfortunate, but real occurence) then I can try to work it out in another way

Comment: Thanks youris , I want a sutiable way for high school level if it is possible , i have tried manytimes but no result

Comment: Can you use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: @YuriyS Why "But if you are not allowed to use Taylor series (an unfortunate, but real occurence)" ? In all basic calculus courses I know limits are way before Taylor polynomials, not to mention Taylor series. As this is is a High School question then this is even sharper.

Comment: [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) for 
$$\frac{(x+1)\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$?

Comment: There's a part of the limit that can be easily dealt with: $$L=1+\lim_{x \to \infty} x \left(\log \left( (1+\frac{1}{x} )^x \right)-1  \right)$$

The second part is tricky to find without L'Hospital or Taylor. Since it's of the type $ \infty \cdot 0$. Obviously, it's equal to $-1/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment, [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) applied twice 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)-1}{\frac{1}{x}}=
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\\
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2 + x^3}}{\frac{2}{x^3}}=
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^3}{x^2+x^3}=\frac{1}{2}$$
It is worth mentioning that both times we are dealing with $\frac{0}{0}$, so L'Hôpital's rule can be applied. L'Hôpital's rule used to be part of the high school program, I hope it still is.

Answer (score 1):

Set $1/x=h\implies h\to0$

$$\lim_h\dfrac{(1+h)\ln(1+h)-h}{h^2}=\lim_h\dfrac{\ln(1+h)-h}h+\lim_h\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h$$

For the first limit, use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

What about the second one?